# docker tag image where you install packages

Tags: macos, docker

I'm trying to tag a local image where I installed some backages to a server and the upload it. It used to work before but for some reason, now when I need it it doesn't work anymore.

I installed the packages, exit the container with "exit" then took the name and performed this command:

docker tag 2747afcd67ee docker.awesomerepo.net/alpine_ssh_tunnel_ready

the image is in the docker ps -a logs:

2747afcd67ee        7328f6f8b418                            "/bin/sh"                21 minutes ago      Exited (0) 15 minutes ago                                                     priceless_galileo

Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you,
Lg.

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: **docker ps** shows containers (an instance of an image), use **docker images** to see images.

Comment: / # ^[[A15mbp-12316:~ xxx$ docker tag ab71ff4220de alpine_ssh_tunnel_ready
Error response from daemon: No such image: ab71ff4220de:latest
15mbp-12316:~ xxx$ docker tag ab71ff4220de docker.awesomerepo/alpine_ssh_tunnel_ready
15mbp-12316:~ xxx$ docker tag 2747afcd67ee docker.awesomerepo.net/alpine_ssh_tunnel_ready
Error response from daemon: No such image: 2747afcd67ee:latest

Comment: So I took the id from the closed image and tried to ta git because it contains my packages

Comment: essentially you want to create an image from a container, see **docker commit** or better yet, create a Dockerfile to create the image the way you want.

Comment: I know that dockefile could be better for this. But. In many situations I prepare a docker container with packages that I am not aware are needed and would like to perform a tag and push it to the repository on the go and not remembering how many packages I installed and so on